# Fast C comparison

Tags: c, comparison, substring

As part of a protocol I'm receiving C string of the following format:
WORD * WORD
Where both WORDs are the same given string.
And, * - is any string of printable characters, NOT including spaces!

So the following are all legal:

- WORD asjdfnkn WORD
- WORD 234kjk2nd32jk WORD

And the following are illegal:

1. WORD akldmWORD
2. WORD asdm zz WORD
3. NOTWORD admkas WORD
4. NOTWORD admkas NOTWORD

Where (1) is missing a trailing space; (2) has 3 or more spaces; (3)/(4) do not open/end with the correct string (WORD).

Of-course this could be implemented pretty straight-forward, however I'm not sure what I'm doing is the most efficient.
Note: WORD is pre-set for a whole run, however could change from run to run.

Currently I'm strncmping each string against "WORD ".
If that checks manually (char-by-char) run over the string, to check for the second space char.
[If found] I then strcmp (all the way) with "WORD".

Would love to hear your solution, with an emphasis on efficiency as I'll be running over millions of theses in real-time.

Comment: can you receive illegal formats?

Comment: Dunno if it's possible in your case, but if you could get the length of the string passed in as well, you could avoid having to iterate over the entire string to find out whether there is a " WORD" substring at the end.  Then you could have an O(1) test.

Comment: @Jeremy: he would still need to iterate over the string to check if there's an extra space.

Comment: @yi_H: Unfortunately I can. That is what I'm trying to check: if the string is malformed.

Comment: @Jeremy: Assuming I could get 'n', how would you do this?

Comment: When you mention 'space' do you really mean 'whitespace'?  In other words, is is valid or invalid to have a `\t` or `\n` character between the two `WORD` bookends?  That can change the details of what functions or algorithms might be used to validate/parse the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you profiled?

There's not much gain to be had here, since you're doing basic string comparisons.  If you want to go for the last few percent of performance, I'd change out the `str...` functions for `mem...` functions.

```
char *bufp, *bufe; // pointer to buffer, one past end of buffer
if (bufe - bufp < wordlen * 2 + 2)
    error();
if (memcmp(bufp, word, wordlen) || bufp[wordlen] != ' ')
    error();
bufp += wordlen + 1;
char *datap = bufp;
char *datae = memchr(bufp, ' ', bufe - buf);
if (!datae || bufe - datae < wordlen + 1)
    error();
if (memcmp(datae + 1, word, wordlen))
    error();
// Your data is in the range [datap, datae).
```

The performance gains are likely less than spectacular.  You have to examine each character in the buffer since each character *could* be a space, and any character in the delimiters *could* be wrong.  Changing a loop to `memchr` is slick, but modern compilers know how to do that for you.  Changing a `strncmp` or `strcmp` to `memcmp` is also probably going to be negligible.

Comment: Good point on `memcmp()` instead of `strcmp()` or `strncmp()`!

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered! WOW! Many thanks! These kind of insights are the reason I ask this question in the first place! 10x!

Comment: I checked the memcmp/strcmp code from glibc reference implementation.  
It is clear why memcmp is a bit better. memcmp treats the the given mem area, as an array of longs (4/8 byte ints). In each comparison it compares 4/8 bytes, instead of the traditional 1-byte-at-a-time. This is great!

Comment: @Trevor: That must be the generic version.  Your system will actually use an SSE4 or SSSE3 version of `strcmp` at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say, have a look at the algorithms in [Handbook of Exact String-Matching Algorithms](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/string.pdf), compare the complexities and choose the one that you like best, implement it.

Or you can use some ready-made implementations.

You have some really classical algorithms for searching strings inside another string here:

[KMP(Knuth-Morris-Pratt)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

[Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-karp)

[Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: String search algorithms aren't needed or useful here, because the expected position of the substring is already known. All that's left to do is compare it.

Comment: Not a solution, but the supplied pdf seems verrrry useful [and a bit fun to read]. +1 for that source! 10x

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a tradeoff to be made between the shortest code and the fastest implementation.  Choices are:

1. The regular expression `^WORD \S+ WORD$` (requires a regex engine)
2. `strchr` on `"WORD "` and a `strrchr` on " WORD" with a lot of messy checks (not really recommended)
3. Walking the whole string character by character, keeping track of the state you are in (scanning first word, scanning first space, scanning middle, scanning last space, scanning last word, expecting end of string).

Option 1 requires the least code but backtracks near the end, and Option 2 has no redeeming qualities. I think you can do option 3 elegantly.  Use a state variable and it will look okay.  Remember to manually enter the last two states based on the length of your word and the length of your overall string and this will avoid the backtracking that a regex will most likely have.

Comment: 1 & 2 are not solving for efficiency which was asked in the question.

Comment: Right you are.  I've qualified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how long the string that is to be checked is?  If not, your are somewhat limited in what you can do.  If you do know how long the string is, you can speed things up a bit.  You have not specified for sure that the '*' part has to be at least one character.  You've also not stipulated whether tabs are allowed, or newlines, or ... is it only alphanumerics (as in your examples) or are punctuation and other characters allowed?  Control characters?

You know how long WORD is, and can pre-construct both the start and end markers.  The function `error()` reports an error (however you need it to be reported) and returns `false`.  The test function might be `bool string_is_ok(const char *string, int actstrlen);`, returning `true` on success and `false` when there is a problem:

```
// Preset variables characterizing the search
static int  wordlen    = 4;
static int  marklen    = wordlen + 1;
static int  minstrlen  = 2 * marklen + 1;  // Two blanks and one other character.
static char bword[]    = "WORD ";          // Start marker
static char eword[]    = " WORD";          // End marker
static char verboten[] = " ";              // Forbidden characters

bool string_is_ok(const char *string, int  actstrlen)
{
    if (actstrlen < minstrlen)
        return error("string too short");
    if (strncmp(string, bword, marklen) != 0)
        return error("string does not start with WORD");
    if (strcmp(string + actstrlen - marklen, eword) != 0)
        return error("string does not finish with WORD");
    if (strcspn(string + marklen, verboten) != actstrlen - 2 * marklen)
        return error("string contains verboten characters");
    return true;
}
```

You probably can't reduce the tests by much if you want your guarantees.  The part that would change most depending on the restrictions in the alphabet is the `strcspn()` line.  That is relatively fast for a small list of forbidden characters; it will likely be slower as the number of characters forbidden is increased.  If you only allow alphanumerics, you have 62 OK and 193 not OK characters, unless you count some of the high-bit set characters as alphabetic too.  That part will probably be slow.  You might do better with a custom function that takes a start position and length and reports whether all characters are OK.  This could be along the lines of:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

static bool ok_chars[256] = { false };

static void init_ok_chars(void)
{
    const unsigned char *ok = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz...0123456789";
    int c;
    while ((c = *ok++) != 0)
        ok_chars[c] = 1;
}

static bool all_chars_ok(const char *check, int numchars)
{
    for (i = 0; i < numchars; i++)
        if (ok_chars[check[i]] == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

You can then use:

```
return all_chars_ok(string + marklen, actstrlen - 2 * marklen);
```

in place of the call to `strcspn()`.

Answer (score 1):

If your "stuffing" should contain only '0'-'9', 'A'-'Z' and 'a'-'z' and are in some encoding based on ASCII (like most Unicode based encodings), then you can skip two comparisons in one of your loops, since only one bit differ between capital and minor characters.
Instead of

```
   ch>='0' && ch<='9' && ch>='A' && ch<='Z' && ch>='a' && ch<='a'
```

you get

```
   ch2 = ch & ~('a' ^ 'A')

   ch>='0' && ch<='9' && ch2>='A' && ch2<='Z'
```

But you better look at the assembler code your compiler generate and do some benchmarking, depending on computer architecture and compiler, this trick could give slower code.

If branching is expensive compared to comparisons on your computer, you can also replace the `&&` with `&`. But most modern compilers know this trick in most situations.

If, on the other hand, you test for any printable glyph from some large character encoding, then it is most likely less expensive to test for white-space glyphs, rather then printable glyph.

Also, compile specifically for the computer that the code will run on and don't forget turn of any generation of debugging-code.

*Added:*

Don't make subroutine calls within your scan loops, unless it is worth it.

Whatever trick you use to speed up your loops, it will diminish if you have to make a sub-routine call within one of them. It is fine to use built-in functions that your compiler inline into your code, but if you use something lika an external regex-library and your compiler is unable to inline those functions (gcc can do that, sometimes, if you ask it to), then making that subroutine call will shuffle a lot of memory around, in worse case between different types of memory (registers, CPU buffers, RAM, harddisk et.c.) and may mess up CPU predictions and pipelines. Unless your text-snippets are very long, so that you spend much time parsing each of them, and the subroutine is effective enough to compensate for the cost of the call, don't do that. Some functions for parsing use call-backs, it might be more effective then you making a lot of subroutine calls from your loops (since the function can scan several pattern-matches in one sweep and bunch several call-backs together outside the critical loop), but that depend on how someone else have written that function and basically it is the same thing as you making the call.

Answer (score 0):

WORD is 4 characters, with uint32_t you could do a quick comparison. You will need a different constant depending on system endianness. The rest seems to be fine.

Since WORD can change you have to precalculate the uint32_t, uint64_t, ... you need depending on the length of the WORD.

Not sure from the description, but if you trust the source you could just chomp the first n+1 and last n+1 characters.

Comment: I think the OP is using "WORD" to stand for an arbitrary word.

Comment: ... and it would only work if the second WORD was a mod4 boundary from the first, which is not the case in the examples he provide....

Answer (score 0):

```
bool check_legal(
        const char *start, const char *end,
        const char *delim_start, const char *delim_end,
        const char **content_start, const char **content_end
) {
  const size_t delim_len = delim_end - delim_start;
  const char *p = start;

  if (start + delim_len + 1 + 0 + 1 + delim_len < end)
    return false;

  if (memcmp(p, delim_start, delim_len) != 0)
    return false;
  p += delim_len;

  if (*p != ' ')
    return false;
  p++;

  *content_start = p;
  while (p < end - 1 - delim_len && *p != ' ')
    p++;
  if (p + 1 + delim_len != end)
    return false;
  *content_end = p;
  p++;

  if (memcmp(p, delim_start, delim_len) != 0)
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

And here is how to use it:

```
const char *line = "who is who";
const char *delim = "who";
const char *start, *end;

if (check_legal(line, line + strlen(line), delim, delim + strlen(delim), &start, &end)) {
  printf("this %*s nice\n", (int) (end - start), start);
}
```

(It's all untested.)

Answer (score 0):

This should return the true/false condition in O(n) time

```
int sameWord(char *str)
{
  char *word1, *word2;
  word1 = word2 = str;

  // Word1, Word2 points to beginning of line where the first word is found

  while (*word2 && *word2 != ' ') ++word2; // skip to first space
  if (*word2 == ' ') ++word2; // skip space

  // Word1 points to first word, word2 points to the middle-filler

  while (*word2 && *word2 != ' ') ++word2; // skip to second space
  if (*word2 == ' ') ++word2; // skip space

  // Word1 points to first word, word2 points to the second word

  // Now just compare that word1 and word2 point to identical strings.

  while (*word1 != ' ' && *word2)
     if (*word1++ != *word2++) return 0; //false
  return *word1 == ' ' && (*word2 == 0 || *word2 == ' ');
}
```

Comment: I don't see O(1) when iterating through a string.

Comment: Fair comment: O(n) :-)   
Anyhow, this is the fastest it can be done with the only knowledge of the string given.  Any of the strcmp/memcmp solutions all looks at the data more than once AND they invoke a function call which slows it down futher unless the compiler is able to inline it.

Comment: My solution only looks once at each byte, and more is not necessary. The function calls are only to well-known functions of the standard library, which at least GCC inlines very well.

Comment: By the way: when you have reached the first space, you should `word2++`.

Comment: @Roland Illig -- The solution should be correct, the word2 pointer should forward to the second space before starting comparison.

Comment: @Soren: Could you please explain the purpose of these 2 lines?   
while (*word2 && *word2 != ' ') ++word2;
while (*word2 && *word2 != ' ') ++word2;

Comment: The word2 pointer starts at the beginning of the content, so the first while-loop fast forwards to the first space, and the second while loop forward the word2 pointer to the second space. -- In both while loops the loop is protected to run past the end of the line by testing for null termination (`*word2` is false when it hits null termination) -- After the second while loop, skips the space and *word1 points to the first character in the first work and *word2 point on the first character in the second word.

Answer (score 0):

using STL find the number of spaces..if they are not two obviously the string is wrong..and using find(algorithm.h) you can get the position of the two spaces and the middle word! Check for WORD at the beginning and the end! you are done..